# Not getting tootip for devexpress form

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

[image]

Hi all,

Please help me,

i have already attached screen shot for problem

Screen 1:
on windows 7 if run cmd or Firefox or vs 2012 and on task bar on mouse hover it shows tool tip on top.

Screen 2:
but if we run any devexpress form then it is not showing tooltip for form .

please help me for the same. is their any property need to set or is their any code for that.

please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Go to design view, select properties toolbar and look for **Text** and **TitleText**.

The same goes for WinForms with the exclusion of TitleText which is added by DevExpress.

Answer (score -1):

The tooltip is automatic. It displays the window's title/caption. If your window does not have a title/caption, then nothing will be displayed.

To fix it, set a title/caption for your window. I'd tell you exactly how to do it, but the DevExpress online documentation is terrible and your question doesn't say which of their packages you're actually using.

Comment: Thanks i am using devexpress 13.2.6 version. is their any property for setting title / caption.